# Javascript: Spread array of an object in an object and change properties inside it only

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where I want to change properties of object in an array. That array is wrapped inside another object.

```js
const defaultData = {
  title: "Title",
  subtitle: "Subtitle",
  books: [
    {
      bookId: "1",
      imageSrc:
        "any.png",
      name: "Issue",
      userOwnsData: true,
      panelsCollected: 0,
      totalPanels: 123,
      link: "https://google.com",
    },
  ],
  bgColor: "black",
};
```

When I spread it like this:

```js
{...defaultData, ...defaultData.books[0], panelsCollected:123} //previously it was 0
```

then it adds another extra object to **parent object** but not update it inside first index of **books array**

How can I just change that **panelsCollected property** without disturbing whole structure as we are using typescript.

**Edit:**

We can change it directly accessing the property too as we know index but that comes with a side effect of manipulating original dataset also which we should avoid and only copy needs to be updated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to spread that object out to update one value? Why not just `defaultData.books[0].panelsCollected = 123`?

Comment: @Andy Yes it will change only one property but what about other data we need. How can i get same structure with just one property being changed.

Comment: What other data? You should probably expand your question code to be representative of the problem you're actually facing.

Comment: @Andy I have an object named `defaultData` and i want to return same structure of it but just one property needs to be updated which was `panelsCollected`. I tried my best to clear everything in question.

Comment: If you know the index of the object in books you can just update that property value as I suggested. You don't necessarily need to create a brand new object by spreading the old one out.

Comment: @Andy What you are mentioning has a side effect that it will manipulate original dataset also. Meanwhile we want only copy of it to be updated as a rule while mutating objects. Question updated with more specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When spreading an object with nested properties with the intention of updating specific properties, think of it in two steps:

1. Spread the original object to copy it (`...`)
2. Redefine the new property values **after** the spread object

In your example we are doing the following:

- Duplicating `defaultData` and assigning an updated `books` property (to be defined in the next step)
- Duplicating the first book (`defaultData.books[0]`) and assigning an updated `panelsCollected` property to it. Then overwriting the existing `books` property with this updated array item

The result is as follows:

```
const defaultData = {
  title: "Title",
  subtitle: "Subtitle",
  books: [
    {
      bookId: "1",
      imageSrc:
        "any.png",
      name: "Issue",
      userOwnsData: true,
      panelsCollected: 0,
      totalPanels: 123,
      link: "https://google.com",
    },
  ],
  bgColor: "black",
};

const newBook = {
  ...defaultData,
  books: [
    {
      ...defaultData.books[0],
      panelsCollected: 123
    }
  ]
}

console.log(newBook)
/*
{
  title: "Title",
  subtitle: "Subtitle",
  books: [
    {
      bookId: "1",
      imageSrc:
        "any.png",
      name: "Issue",
      userOwnsData: true,
      panelsCollected: 123,
      totalPanels: 123,
      link: "https://google.com",
    },
  ],
  bgColor: "black",
};
*/
```

If for example the `books` property was 1000 items long, you would instead use have to find the specific book in your array using an array method (e.g. `find` / `findIndex`) and update it, e.g.

```
const bookToUpdateIndex = defaultData.books.findIndex(book => book.bookId === '1')

const updatedBooks = [...defaultData.books]
updatedBooks[bookToUpdateIndex] = {
  ...updatedBooks[bookToUpdateIndex],
  panelsCollected: 123
}

const newBook = {
  ...defaultData,
  books: updatedBooks
}
```

Comment: `findIndex(book => bookId === '1')` should be `findIndex(book => book.bookId === '1')`

Comment: And also this answer also __mutates__ the original object. @SulemanAhmad which isn't what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `find` and the spread syntax an alternative approach (but not necessarily the most performant) might be to copy the object by stringifying it, and then reparsing that string. And then you can just update the object at the index you need.

```js
const defaultData={title:"Title",subtitle:"Subtitle",books:[{bookId:"1",imageSrc:"any.png",name:"Issue",userOwnsData:!0,panelsCollected:0,totalPanels:123,link:"https://google.com"}],bgColor:"black"};

const copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(defaultData));
copy.books[0].panelsCollected = 123;

console.log(defaultData);
console.log(copy);
```

Comment: const newBook = {
  ...defaultData,
  books: [
    {
      ...defaultData.books[0],
      panelsCollected: 123
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I was looking for this part which does not mutate original object.

Comment: But it only works if you have one book. @SulemanAhmad. I was indicating the second part of that answer which would mutate the original object.